# Solving SUPW from ZCO 2014

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

While practicing for the upcoming ZCO I cam across [this](https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO14002) problem , here is an excerpt from it,

> In ICO School, all students have to participate regularly in SUPW.
>   There is a different SUPW activity each day, and each activity has its
>   own duration. The SUPW schedule for the next term has been announced,
>   including information about the number of minutes taken by each
>   activity.
>
> Nikhil has been designated SUPW coordinator. His task is to assign
>   SUPW duties to students, including himself. The school's rules say
>   that no student can go three days in a row without any SUPW duty.
>
> Nikhil wants to find an assignment of SUPW duty for himself that
>   minimizes the number of minutes he spends overall on SUPW.

Thinking of a DP solution , I took a a day added it to next 3 days and took their minimum value to get the next day when Nikhil should do a task, but I pretty much messed up in the comparison thing, here is what I have worked up ,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

int calcmintime(std::vector<std::vector<int> >matrix,int n,int j,std::vector<int>duty){
    int time1 = matrix[0][j];
    int time2 = matrix[1][j];
    int time3 = matrix[2][j];
    if(time1+time2+time3 == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(time1 < time2 && time1 < time3 ){
        j = j + 1;
        return (duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,j,duty));
    }
    if(time2 < time3 && time2 < time1 ){
        j = j + 2;
        return (duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,j,duty));
    }
    if(time3 < time2 && time3 < time1 ){
        j = j + 3;
        return (duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,j,duty));
    }
    if(time1 == time2 && time1 < time3){
        int a = j+1;
        int b = j+2;
        int forA = duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,a,duty);
        int forB = duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,b,duty);
        if(forA > forB){
            return forB;
        }else{
            return forA;
        }
    }
    if(time1 == time3 && time1 < time2){
        int a = j+1;
        int b = j+3;
        int forA = duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,a,duty);
        int forB = duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,b,duty);
        if(forA > forB){
            return forB;
        }else{
            return forA;
        }
    }
    if(time2 == time3 && time2 < time1){
        int a = j+3;
        int b = j+2;
        int forA = duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,a,duty);
        int forB = duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,b,duty);
        if(forA > forB){
            return forB;
        }else{
            return forA;
        }
    }
    if(time1 == time2 && time2 == time3){
        int a = j+1;
        int b = j+2;
        int c = j+3;
        int forA = duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,a,duty);
        int forB = duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,b,duty);
        int forC = duty[j]+calcmintime(matrix,n,c,duty);
        int result = forA;
        if(forB < result){
            result = forB;
        }
        if(forC < result){
            result = forC;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

int main(){
    int days;
    std::cin >> days;
    std::vector<int>dutyTime(days);
    //std::cout << "got it" << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<days;i++){
        std::cin >> dutyTime[i];
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >timeMat(3,std::vector<int>(days,0));
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<days-1-i;j++){
            timeMat[i][j] = dutyTime[j] + dutyTime[j+1+i];
            //std::cout << timeMat[i][j] << ' ' << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << std::endl;
        }
        //std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    int mintime = INT_MAX;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        int newmin = dutyTime[i]+calcmintime(timeMat,days,i,dutyTime);
        if(newmin < mintime){
            mintime = newmin;
        }
    }
    std::cout << mintime << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ok this code gives the correct answer 2 out of 12 times , so I am going in the right way but should have missed some cases which can upset my program.
Can anyone suggest a better approach for this problem?

**Update :**
I have tried another approach (though it will have problems with inputs less than 4) , but the result is same :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int>dutyTime(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cin >> dutyTime[i];
    }
    std::vector<int>bestTime(n);
    bestTime[0] = dutyTime[0] + std::min(dutyTime[1],std::min(dutyTime[2],dutyTime[3]));
    bestTime[1] = dutyTime[1] + std::min(dutyTime[2],std::min(dutyTime[3],dutyTime[4]));
    bestTime[2] = dutyTime[2] + std::min(dutyTime[3],std::min(dutyTime[4],dutyTime[5]));
    for(int i=3;i<n-3;i++){
        bestTime[i] = std::min(bestTime[i-3],std::min(bestTime[i-2],bestTime[i-1])) + std::min(dutyTime[i+1],std::min(dutyTime[i+2],dutyTime[i+3]));
    }
    std::cout << bestTime[n-4] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Note** : Sorry since it is for competitive programming , I havent documented it yet

Comment: Huh! `Line 1: A single integer N, the number of days in the future for which SUPW data is available... 1 ≤ N ≤ 2×10^5` That ICO school *is* something: 200'000days is > 500 years.

Comment: Huh , thought someone answered my question...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it pretty quick and lot less code :)

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int>dutyTime(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cin >> dutyTime[i];
    }
    std::vector<int>bestTime(n);
    bestTime[0] = dutyTime[0];
    bestTime[1] = dutyTime[1];
    bestTime[2] = dutyTime[2];
    for(int i=3;i<n;i++){
        bestTime[i] = dutyTime[i]+std::min(bestTime[i-1],std::min(bestTime[i-2],bestTime[i-3]));
    }

    std::cout << std::min(bestTime[n-1],std::min(bestTime[n-2],bestTime[n-3])) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation:**

For the first 3 days the minimum possible time can only be the time allotted for the day itself, for the next days we could simply select the minimum of the last three days and add with the time allotted to the current day, tada at the end the minimum of the last three days is the minimum possible time Nikhil can spend in the camp.

Comment: @FanilGandhi your task has 8 ones, so if I take 3rd and the 5th one, i still satisfy the criteria and the lowest possible total will be 2 not 3 , 
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 -> thats the eight days of work.

Comment: Ya right , it's a typo. I wanted to add 9 `1` to it.

Comment: Suppose the values provided are 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1. the ans would be 3 but your algo wouldn't work

Comment: Sure? Please check again.